# Qual é a relação entre a camada de aplicação e a classe controladora?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, arquitetura-de-software, projeto-de-software

O livro *Utilizando UML e Padrões* apresenta brevemente a arquitetura em camadas, uma das quais é a de aplicação, também chamada de controlador da aplicação.

Apresenta também o padrão GRASP chamado Controlador, que fornece diretrizes para a criação de uma classe controladora (que não é o controller do MVC - este último pertence à camada de UI). (Quantos controladores!)

A função dessa classe controladora é apenas receber e delegar eventos de sistema externos (em geral de UI) para a camada de domínio. Ela pode pertencer à camada de aplicação ou à de domínio, dependendo dos frameworks utilizados. Ela é a primeira classe além da camada de UI a receber eventos de sistema. É uma classe inventada (uma "invenção pura", no linguajar do GRASP).

Estou tentando conciliar esse conhecimento com o conhecimento do que faz uma camada de aplicação.

Por não fazer nada além de delegar, esse controlador é compatível com a camada de aplicação? Pode ser associado à mesma? É talvez uma primeira versão do que poderá ter a camada de aplicação?

Essa camada não executa lógica que coordena os objetos do modelo de domínio e de outras camadas?

Com a implementação e posterior evolução da aplicação, como uma se transforma em outra?

Exemplos, se possíveis, em Java, se possível.

Comment: Relacionada (SOen): https://stackoverflow.com/q/5368085/2241463

Answer (score 1):

> (Quantos controladores!)

Sim, a nomenclatura e a "função" é parecida para os vários controladores, porém o contexto difere.

Há o controlador de interface do usuário e controlador de domínio como padrões mais usados.

O Controlador de UI coordena o acesso a View, em um padrão MVC.

Controlador de domínio coordena o acesso ao domínio, e é chamado de camada de serviço (Fowler) ou camada de aplicação (Evans). Ambas são camadas indiretas (Facade Design Pattern), usadas para separar classes entre subsistemas / camadas. Ele traz modularidade e melhor capacidade de manutenção (você pode trocar o domínio por serviços remotos ou trocar a visão do HTML para o Flex, e apenas mudar a camada de indireção) O Controlador GRASP parece ser um híbrido de ambos.

Há ainda o controlador de frente (Front Controller) em sistemas que precisam, a partir de um ponto de acesso único, decidir a quem enviar a responsabilidade de uma requisição (Sistemas Web sobre HTTP por exemplo).

Como cada "tipo" de controlador tem uma implementação diferente, acredito que seja mais fácil pesquisar pelo nome de contexto do controlador que deseja.

Espero ter ajudado.